# What tools and kernel features some desktop environments use, to monitor battery level

Tags: laptop, battery, power, gnome

I have noticed some strange behavior of battery charge indicator in Gnome and Cinnamon. When you plug charger into laptop, it updates battery charging status(charging/discharging) only when battery charge percentage changes. Herewith, it can't detect charger being plugged in instantly. So could someone please explain, on what tools, battery indicator in Gnome, bases it indications?
Because there's other desktop environments such like Deepin DE, that detects battery charger plug event instantly. Also such low-level tool as `acpi` (do not confuse it with power control standart/protocol), also detects battery charging status instantly.

So what special are in Gnome battery widget/monitor, that it can't detect charging status instantly and is it a hardware or software issue? I'm posessing with Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro 2019 with battery which vendor reported as SUNWODA-R15B01W